# Why is 'super' a keyword rather than a method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, language-design, super

In Ruby, [`super`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html) is a [keyword](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-super) rather than a method.

Why was it designed this way?

Ruby's design tends toward implementing as much as possible as methods; keywords are usually reserved for language features that have their own grammar rules. `super`, however, looks and acts like a method call.

(I know it would be cumbersome to implement `super` in pure Ruby, since it would have to parse the method name out of `caller`, or [use a trace_func](http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Binding.html). This alone wouldn't prevent it from being a method, because plenty of [Kernel](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html)'s methods are not implemented in pure Ruby.)

Comment: It behaves a little differently, in that if you don't pass arguments, all of the current arguments (and block, if present) are passed along... I'm not sure how that would work as a method.

Comment: @d11wtq gave the correct reason, maybe it should be an answer rather than a comment though?

Comment: @d11wtq: This is a great point, please make it an answer. It had actually occurred to me, but I wondered if that was the only reason.

Comment: Added my comment as an answer as requested, with an example (not for you, but for future readers) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It behaves a little differently, in that if you don't pass arguments, all of the current arguments (and block, if present) are passed along... I'm not sure how that would work as a method.

To give a rather contrived example:

```
class A
  def example(a, b, c)
    yield whatever(a, b) + c
  end
end

class B < A
  def example(a, b, c)
    super * 2
  end
end
```

I did not need to handle the yield, or pass the arguments to `super`.  In the cases where you specifically want to pass different arguments, then it behaves more like a method call.  If you want to pass no arguments at all, you must pass empty parentheses (`super()`).

It simply doesn't have quite the same behaviour as a method call.

Comment: I think the most important aspect to your answer is that *there is no way for a method to know whether it was called with or without parentheses*. Since `super` is a keyword, this determination is baked into the grammar itself. I'm fairly sure, although not certain, that Ruby's internals would provide access to the arguments and block of the caller.

Answer (score 1):

`super` doesn't automatically call the parent class's method. If you imagine the inheritance hierarchy of a ruby class as a list, with the class at the bottom and `Object` at the top, when ruby sees the the `super` keyword, rather than just check the the parent class, it moves up the entire list until it finds the first item that has a method defined with that name.

I'm careful to say item because it could also be a **module**. When you include a module in to a class, it is wrapped in an anonymous superclass and put above your class in the list I talked about before, so that means if you had a method defined for your class that was also defined in the module, then calling super from the class's implementation would call the module's implementation, and not the parent class's:

```
class Foo
  def f
    puts "Foo"
  end
end

module Bar
  def f
    puts "Bar"
    super
  end
end

class Foobar < Foo
  include Bar

  def f
    puts "Foobar"
    super
  end
end

foobar = Foobar.new
foobar.f
  # =>
  # Foobar
  # Bar
  # Foo
```

And I don't believe that it is possible to access this 'inheritance list' from the ruby environment itself, which would mean this functionality would not be available (However useful it is; I'm not every sure if this was an intended feature.)

Comment: `Class#ancestors` give you the "inheritance list", so this would be trivial

Comment: As I point out in my question, `Kernel#super` wouldn't have to be implemented in pure Ruby, many of the methods on `Kernel` are implmented in C (in MRI, at least).

Comment: @riffraff Yeah, it does, but the problem arises when you use `extend` on an instance. So, say rather than the above case, `Foobar` does not include module `Bar` but rather I extend `foobar`: `foobar.extend Bar`. At this point, if you checked the return value of `Class#ancestors`, `Bar` would not appear in it. (That is, if you checked `Foobar.ancestors` *or* if you checked `foobar.class.ancestors`)

Comment: ah, true, but you can still see them if you look at the singleton class: `(class <<c ;self; end).ancestors`

Answer (score 0):

Hm, good qustion. I'm not sure how else (besides using `super`) you would you reference the super version of a given method.

You can't simply call the method by name, because the way that polymorphism works (how it figures out *which version* of that method to actually call, based on the object class) would cause your method to call itself, spinning into an infinite set of calls, and resulting in a stack overflow.

Comment: Could you please clarify which method is "that method" when you say "the super version of that method"?

Comment: Sorry, clarified the wording a bit. I simply meant, "The method in question - whatever method it is you're talking about."

Comment: you can invoke a superclass independently from the fact that a subclass has overriden it by getting an `UnboundMethod` object from  the superclass and binding it to the subclass instance. E.g. `SuperKlass.instance_method(:foo).bind(SubKlass.new).call(arguments)`

Comment: I'm not asking why `super` exists, I'm asking why it's a keyword, rather than a method on, say, Kernel. If it were, you would still be able to call `super` in much the same way you do now.