# why puts is not printing the name and id instance variable which is intitialized in superclass?

Tags: ruby

```
# super class
class Wages 
  attr_accessor :name ,:id

  def initialize(name="first",id=0.0)
    self.name=name
    self.id=id
  end
end

class HourEmployee<Wages
  attr_accessor :hours ,:payperhour

  def initialize
    puts "please enter the no of hours and payperhour"
    hours=0.0
    payperhour=0.0
  end

  def pay_per_hour
    puts "the employee name #{self.name}" 
    puts "employee id is #{@id}"
    puts "employee Wages for his work are "
    self.calculate
  end

  def calculate
    puts "please enter the no of hours"
    @Wages = hours*payperhour
    puts "#{@Wages}"
  end
end

a=HourEmployee.new
a.hours=40
a.payperhour=10
a.pay_per_hour
```

why the code is not printing the name and the id which it is supposed to print
i have initialized the class wages in the superclass but when i am printing the name it is giving blank space for both name and id

Answer (score 0):

You need to call parent class' constructor from derived class.  Use [`super`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454382/why-is-super-a-keyword-rather-than-a-method-in-ruby) to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call constructor for the `superClass`

```
class HourEmployee < Wages
  ...

  def initialize
    super
    puts "please enter the no of hours and payperhour"
    hours=0.0
    payperhour=0.0
  end
  ...
end
```

For example

```
class A
  def initialize
    puts "Class A constructor"
  end
end

class B < A
  def initialize
    puts "Class B constructor"
  end
end

class C < A
  def initialize
    super
    puts "Class C constructor"
  end
end

a = A.new
# Class A constructor
b = B.new
# Class B constructor
c = C.new
# Class A constructor
# Class C constructor
```

Comment: Ideally, class `B` should also call `super`

Comment: It should call, but it is for purposes left out, to show the diference